# what is 'missing print filter'?

Tags: printing

I run win10 and ubuntu 16.04 on the same computer. Epson artisan 720 wireless lan printer worked mormally for about 6mo.,but now I get 'missing print filter for printer epson 720' in the status message box. Printer still works normally in win10. 
I have not found a solution on google. I'm still an ubuntu newbie.
Thanks

Comment: Did you install Epson printer drivers? You may need to re-install them.

Comment: " I have not found a solution on google" 1st hit on google: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660566  2nd hit: http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-escpr/ Seems to be the answer to your problem? You need to install cups support  for your artisan 720 :P

Comment: In addition to the link given above try [here](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-Artisan_720_Series), __Note__: actually for __725-835__ but used for __720__.